# How to use JSDoc with destructured imports?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I am using VSCode as my NodeJS editor and the `Preview JSDOC` extension.

I wonder how I can use JSDoc with restructured imports. See the example below.

I created a module, `Module A`:

```js
/**
 * Some function description
 * @return a string + 1234
 */
const myFuncA = (someParams) => {
  return `${someParams} 1234` // or whatever
};

/**
 * This is a string.
 */
const myPropB = "A string";

// ...

module.exports = {
  myFuncA, 
  myPropB
}
```

In module B, I'd like to use some properties or functions from module A: 
`Module B`:

```
const { myFuncA } = require('../moduleA');

const propA = myFuncA(4321);
```

However, when hovering over `myFuncA` (or when typing `myFuncA(...`), the description is not shown.

I'm new to JSDoc, however, [their docs](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html) don't cover my specific case.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for answer for this as well, and I think the best thing for this solution is to use the `@memberof module:<your-module-name>` syntax.

So in Module B at the top you would add something like this

```
/** module MyModuleName */

const { myFuncA } = require('../moduleA');
```

Then in Module A you would add the `@memberof module:<module-name>` decorator.

```
/**
 * Some function description
 * @return a string + 1234
 * @memberof module:MyModuleName
 */
const myFuncA = (someParams) => {
  return `${someParams} 1234` // or whatever
};
```

Extra Information:
As I was looking for a solution to this problem, I had the assumption that JSDoc would resolve imports. JSDoc does not resolve imports, which makes a lot of sense. If you want a function to belong to another module, you have to let JSDocs know. Credit to this [github issue thread](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1002) which helped me settle on this answer.